# Styling an active state throug the active classname

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have a set of tabs with 2 buttons used to open the tabs. I have been able to style the normal and hover states for the tabs, however I have been unsuccessful with styling the active state.

Since this uses an external library for tabs, the button is marked active through a classname so I have to use the `.active` class rather than `:active` selector.

The element in question is as follows: 
`<a class="nav-link skills-tab active" id="design-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#design" role="tab" aria-controls="design" aria-selected="true">Design</a>`

I have tried styling through a combination of various class and id combinations such as:

`#design-tab .active`

`.nav-link .skills-tab .active`

`#design-tab .nav-link .active`

Unfortunately none of these seem to be working. I think there is other style on the website preveting this one from going through, thus I am trying to find the right style to overwrite it. Even `!important` is not working.

The link to the webpage is here if you want to take a look at the work in progress to get a better idea: 
http://eg-graphics.com/Website%20New/about-us.html

Answer (score 2):

`#design-tab .nav-link .active` this one will never work because `.active` is being a child of `.nav-link` where in fact they are only on the same element.

Can you try using this one?

```css
.nav-link.active {
    background: 
    green !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this #skillsTab.nav.nav-tabs li a.active

Answer (score 0):

The other answers were correct, I just want to expand on what they were saying by stating the cause of my issue.

By having spaces between my class names in the CSS, I was calling for children of classes rather than the same element with multiple classnames. The solution was to not include spaces when calling the classnames in CSS.

So instead of `#design-tab .active` I should have been doing `#design-tab.active`.